# How can I derive the function?

Tags: calculus

My function is 
$$f(x)=\int_{0.5}^{\sin(x)} e^{\arcsin(t)} dt$$
for $x∈(−π/2,π/2)$.

I'm stuck whether the derivative is $f'(x) = e^{\arcsin(x)}$ or $f'(x) = e^{\arcsin(\sin(x))}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $F(t)$ be a primitive of the integrand. The integral then becomes $F(\sin(x))-F(0.5)$. Now take the derivative:
$$F’(\sin(x))\cdot\cos(x)$$
and simplify.